# lighttpd: opening errorlog failed: Permission denied

Tags: linux, lighttpd

this happens when I restart the lighttpd and it backups the old log and creates new one.

Is there any way so I don't have to changed permissions or ownership for that file every time the server is restarted and new log file created?

the file in question before doing `chmod 777 *` in the log directory was

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root eduserver 1.9M Jun 16 13:41 access.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root eduserver  79K Apr 29 09:45 access.log-20110429.bz2*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root eduserver  53K Apr 30 09:45 access.log-20110430.bz2*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root eduserver  55K May  4 09:45 access.log-20110504.bz2*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root eduserver 109K May 13 09:45 access.log-20110513.bz2*
```

Comment: why do you want the log files executable?

Comment: I don't want it executable, I just used 777. The server is not accessible from outside so I didn't worry if it's 777 or 555. The point is that I don't won't to run `chmod` manually every time the server is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following things:

1- Edit the start/stop/restart script by doing the needed `chmod` and/or `chown` commands. So, it will be done automatically each time you restart the server.

2- Add your user to the needed group if applicable. So, there is no need to do `sudo` or change the permissions. Suppose the restart process creates a new file which can be read by group `lighttpd`. Add your user to this group.

By the way, if you can use logrotate, it has an option to specify the file permissions. As an example, you can use `create 640 root adm`.

Comment: would you know which file I need to edit to specify the file permissions for logrotate?

Comment: If you are using logrotate, you need to look for a file named something like `lighttpd` under `/etc/logrotate.d/`. This folder usually keeps the logrotate config files.

Comment: found it. I guess that `chmod 644 /opt/eduserver/log/access.log
` is what I need to change. Any idea how to test that it works?